# How to determine the balance of available wallets by seed phrase?

Tags: python, ethereum, seed

I have a task to determine the balance of the wallet by the seed phrase. I use python to generate a child wallet address from it and make an api request. Everything works fine, but I only generate a wallet for one address: `m/44'/0'/0'/0 (BTC)` But some seed phrases turn out to be empty. And when I insert them into a crypto wallet. Shows that there is a balance, but a different address. Since there are a lot of child wallet addresses (isn't it?), I don't think checking everything is a good idea. The question is, how do wallets do it, how do I do it? **I would be glad even just a verbal algorithm)**